# Power app Data table iteration.

Tags: powerapps

I want to iterate through each row of the data table check for values and update the value in the newly created column.

Are there any blogs or tutorials which have described power app data table iteration and code syntax it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no way to iterate the items in a DataTable. You can, however, pull the data into a collection and iterate the collection using [ForAll function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-forall).  Then display the collection in a DataTable.

You can also create a new issue in the [PowerApps Ideas Board](https://aka.ms/powerapps-ideas) to make a suggestion to the product team to add this to the DataTable control.

Comment: I am not able to send email from ForAll function. My requirement is to iterate through all rows one by one and sends an email notification.

Comment: For scenarios like iterating rows and sending email notification or other actions, I would look at Microsoft Flow.  It uses the same connectors as PowerApps.

Comment: With the help of Concat() function you are able to iterate through all the rows. I called this function inside Office365.SendEmail() function. If you want I can share the code.